How to populate a collection with contents of many files asynchronously while not reading more than N files at the same time?
I have a file processing pipeline, where at some point I want to load certain files into memory asynchronously with no more than mdop files being read at the same time.
The names of the files are consumed from a BlockingCollection and the binary content is cached in a dictionary.
(The progress object is there to help me track the progress, but it is not relevant to this question)
My current implementation uses System.Reactive:
private static Task PreloadBinariesAsync(BlockingCollection<IProjectEx> inputs, int mdop, ConcurrentDictionary<string, byte[]> binaries, Progress progress) => inputs
    .GetConsumingEnumerable()
    .Select(p => Observable.FromAsync(() => ReadAllBytesAsync(p.TargetPath)))
    .Merge(mdop, ThreadPoolScheduler.Instance)
    .ForEachAsync(o =>
    {
        progress.IncAsmFileCachedCount();
        binaries[o.FilePath] = o.Bytes;
    });

private static async Task<(string FilePath, byte[] Bytes)> ReadAllBytesAsync(string filePath) => (filePath, await FS.ReadAllBytesAsync(filePath).ConfigureAwait(false));

This implementation works, but I am not sure if System.Reactive fits the best here.
I am very much open to better alternatives, if needed I can change BlockingCollection to Channel or something else, but it has to be part of the Consumer/Producer bus.
P.S.
Unfortunately, I am constrained to use the .NET Framework.

Inserting a SemaphoreSlim is a quick way to limit the concurrency of a single async method, no matter how it is called.

Hmm, I have not thought about it, while it does sound easy - a loop with the semaphore collecting the tasks in progress or something like that. Could you post your answer so that I could credit you?

I wouldn't recommend using the Rx for parallel processing, because this is not the intended purpose of this library. Its intended purpose is working with streams of events. The shortcomings of Rx become apparent as soon as you start to care about exceptions.

Nowadays the API of choice for solving this kind of problems is the Parallel.ForEachAsync (.NET 6). Since you are targetting the .NET Framework, and presumably you don't want to use the synchronous Parallel.ForEach, you could consider using a custom Parallel.ForEachAsync implementation like the one found here.

A quick way to ensure you only ever read from MAX_COUNT files, no matter how many times the method is called is to use a SemaphoreSlim;
private static SemaphoreSlim semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(MAX_COUNT);
private static async Task<(string FilePath, byte[] Bytes)> ReadAllBytesAsync(string filePath) {
    await semaphore.WaitAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    try{
         return (filePath, await FS.ReadAllBytesAsync(filePath).ConfigureAwait(false));
    }finally{
        semaphore.Release();
    }
}

This will stall the method, without blocking a thread, until another in-progress call releases the semaphore.

Hmm, but you still keep the observable pipeline?

You can try to start as many method calls as you want, it's then the semaphore which will limit concurrency.

But isn't it wasteful to keep all the rest around, if it does not matter anymore? Plus carrying the shortcomings of Rx as mentioned by Theodor Zoulias?

I do not understand how your approach without replacing the entire Rx pipeline is any better than what I have already. In my code the concurrency is reached through the combination of Observable.FromAsync and the Merge extension method. Your replacement of the ReadAllBytesAsync does not change that, so why bother with your implementation at all? This cannot be the right answer.
